# Right click "save as" selects jpg image instead of webp, but webp is displayed

Tags: html, image, apache, .htaccess, webp

I'm using .htaccess to serve webp images to browsers that support it.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} image/webp
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.webp -f
RewriteRule (.+)\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$ $1.webp [T=image/webp,E=REQUEST_image]
Header append Vary Accept env=REQUEST_image
AddType image/webp .webp
```

[Source: WebP images with htaccess](https://github.com/vincentorback/WebP-images-with-htaccess)

Basically what it does is return a .webp image instead of the requested jpg/png/gif, from the same location, if it exists and is supported.

This works fine in Chrome, Firefox, IE11, Edge... Haven't tested Safari.

My issue is however that when I right click on the website, "save as", it automatically selects a .jpg version. If a .jpg version doesn't exist it tries to save the whole html. Intended behaviour would be for it to save the displayed .webp version, if it is used. Weirdly enough it does try to save the .webp in Firefox when doing the same, but when I try the same thing using Page info in Firefox (ctrl+i on Windows), it selects the .jpg.

How is this even possible?
Is there something missing/wrong with this?

I checked that the displayed image is an actual webp, and it is. Both content-type and file size matches that of the webp.

Comment: I am afraid you are looking at one of the many inconsequent aspects of file handling in todays operating systems. Reason is that far too long the idea of "file name extensions" has been considered a clever idea to tell apart file type. Instead things moved on to specified mime types these days, but still you have these old fashioned approaches all over the place. Legacy code. Because it is cheap and kind of works (for > 99% of all cases and users), so no one really cares. That is especially true for the MS-Windows platform.

Comment: @arkascha I thought so at first aswell, but then I did some tests. I can somewhat confirm that Chrome does not care all that much about the file name, because when I directed the requested image to an image script instead (which returned the webp, but without the same headers), then the "save as" correctly assumed webp. So the only difference was that I used Accept-Encoding instead of Accept in the Vary header. I'm no expert, but does that mean it's some sort of caching issue? I tried with the htaccess code again, but changed the Vary header to Accept-Encoding aswell, and that also worked.

Comment: @arkascha I should probably do some more tests, but at least that proves that it doesn't only take into account the file name extension in the img tag. To clarify, all my tests has src="path/to/img.jpg", and with Accept it displayed webp, but tried to save as jpg, while with Accept-Encoding it displayed webp and tried to save as webp.

Answer (score 0):

my working solution is:

---

## Check if browser supports WebP images

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} image/webp
```

## Check if WebP replacement image exists

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_URI} -f
```

## Serve WebP image instead

```
RewriteRule (.+)\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$ $1.webp [T=image/webp,E=REQUEST_image]
```

---

so try to change `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.webp -f` to

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_URI} -f
```

Tested on Safari and Firefox.

Comment: This is just wrong. %{REQUEST_URI} is the requested file (jpg/png/gif), so your method simply checks if the requested file exists but then serves a webp instead. It never checks for a webp. Either way, I think you missunderstood my question. The htaccess works just fine, the issue is described below it.

Comment: I am afraid that you are right, my misunderstood. Sorry :)